1Gbe Interface stops working when MTU set to 9100 on 100G interface
I have a server with 2x1gbe ports LOM and a single port 100G nic.
Our 1gbe network is different than our 100G network and both have access to the internet. I would like to be able to use both interfaces since our 100G network is way more complex than just hooking up an RJ45 cable and SSHing into the server if there is issues.
The problem I am having is:
When I setup my interfaces in netplan
network:
  ethernets:
    enp195s0f0:
      dhcp4: true
      mtu: 1500
    enp195s0f1:
      dhcp4: true
      mtu: 1500
    ens33np0:
      dhcp4: yes
      mtu: 9100
    enx1ae99e633d6d:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2

I can no longer ping 8.8.8.8 through the 1gbe ports anymore. Our 100G switches need the 9100 MTU so if we want to use that interface it needs to be there. If I remove the MTU 9100 I can ssh into the machine through the 1g port again.
I have a feeling this has something to do with the default interface in Ubuntu but I don't know enough to set this up properly. This is the output of ip r
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp195s0f1 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.7 metric 100 
default via 10.0.0.1 dev ens33np0 proto dhcp src 10.0.5.21 metric 100 
10.0.0.0/20 dev ens33np0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.5.21 
10.0.0.1 dev ens33np0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.5.21 metric 100 
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp195s0f1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.0.7 
192.168.0.1 dev enp195s0f1 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.7 metric 100 

My ideal end state is that the application that need high bandwidth access to the internet will use the 100G interface and I can continue using the 1g for my access and management. I have a feeling I need to set the 1g as a primary then manually configure the application to use the 100G but Id love a push in the right direction.
Thanks,
Alec
